# How to find factor (coefficient) in given function Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series

$$f(x)=x^3+\sin x$$ is given function. Interval is: $$(-π,π)$$ Fourier series is $$f(x)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n}\cos(nx)+b_{n}\sin(nx))$$ I have to find $$b_{5}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all Fourier series of the form
$$f(x)=\frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n}\cos{(nx)}+b_{n}\sin{(nx)})$$
The  values of $a_n,b_n$ are given by
$$a_n=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos{(nx)}dx$$
$$b_n=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin{(nx)}dx$$
So for $b_5$ we need
$$b_5=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi (x^3+\sin{(x)})\sin{(5x)}dx$$
Which can be seperated and integrated using integration by parts.